# Hidden cell value changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm wondering how to react on cell changed event but when the column is hidden.

DataGridView.CellValueChanged fires only on visible columns. But how to do it on invisible columns?

Comment: What is the way of changing the cell value in hidden column? Is your datagridview using databinding to some source and values there change?

Comment: Yes. The value changes as a result of some filter